# How to apply steady state solution into this question

Tags: calculus

[image]

This is what my study guide defined as the steady state solution

**If $h(a)=0$ for some constant $a$, then the constant function $y=a$ is a solution of the DE. We sometimes called this a steady state solution.**

From what I interpret you are focused on finding the solutions of $y$ and you would let $dy/dx$ equal to $0$. You would also let any non $y$ term equal to $0$ as well. Does that simply mean that the steady state solution for this question would be equal to zero or am I interpreting the definition wrong?

Comment: In your study guide, what is $h$ supposed to be?

Comment: @Mattos Just function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it. A steady state solution is a fixed value of $y$ for which $dy/dx$ is $0$ and so $y$ does not have to change as the state evolves.

In this case, $$(y=0)\rightarrow (dy/dx=0)$$ so that is all you need.